# Print Excel sheet from MS Access VBA to user selected printer

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to print Excel sheet (Single sheet) which is stored in a path of local computer using a click of button on MS Access form. For some business reasons I need to provide flexibility to the user to select a printer from the list of printers which are configured on his PC. I am showing the names of these printers in MS Access drop down list. The code is provided below:-

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim prtLoop As Printer
   cmbPrinter.RowSource = ""
   For Each prtLoop In Application.Printers
     With prtLoop
      cmbPrinter.AddItem .DeviceName
     End With
   Next prtLoop
   Me.cmbPrinter = Me.cmbPrinter.ItemData(0)
End Sub

Private Sub cmbPrinter_AfterUpdate()
    Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(cmbPrinter.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    'wks is already set to Excel sheet which needs to be printed
    wks.PrintOut
End Sub
```

However the print is always going to default printer which is already configured on the PC and not to the printer which is chosen by the user from the drop down.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: The `.PrintOut` method can take an `ActivePrinter` parameter. I've never used this method myself - but I imagine this might help you point to the right printer? [Worksheet.PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.printout)

Comment: Maybe this is just setting default printer for Access, not Excel. Show code that sets Excel object. Try using Excel object instead of Application.

Comment: Thanks. comment of ArcherBird resolved this. I have not tried suggestion of June 7 since the first comment solved my problem.